# Date format input being saved in wrong format in .csv - R Shiny DataTable

Tags: r, shiny, datatable

In this program in R Shiny, I have a function that reads a .csv and saves input. One of those inputs is a Date.

When I use the app for the first time, it saves the input and the output table is displayed properly. However, when I close and open again to input another entry, it saves as a numeric input, instead of a date input.

Data Table image

[image: 1]

**Code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTime)
library(lubridate)


# UI 
ui <- navbarPage("Menu",
           tabPanel("Perfil",
                    sidebarLayout(
                      sidebarPanel(
                        helpText("Introduza as suas informações nos campos abaixo."),
                        textInput(inputId = "name",  label = "Nome",  value = ""),
                        textInput(inputId = "email",  label = "E-mail",  value = ""),
                        textInput(inputId = "address",  label = "Morada",  value = ""),
                        numericInput(inputId = "phone",  label = "Número de telemóvel",  value = ""),
                        numericInput(inputId = "utente",  label = "Número de utente",  value = ""),
                        numericInput(inputId = "age",  label = "Idade",  value = ""),
                        numericInput(inputId = "weight", label = "Peso (kg)", value = ""),
                        numericInput(inputId = "height", label = "Altura (cm)",  value = ""),
                        actionButton("go", "Atualizar"),
                        
                      ),
                      mainPanel(
                        h4("Nome:", textOutput("name", container = span)),
                        h4("Email:", textOutput("email", container = span)),
                        h4("Morada:", textOutput("address", container = span)),
                        h4("Contacto:", textOutput("phone", container = span)),
                        h4("Nº de Utente:", textOutput("utente", container = span)),
                        h4("Idade:", textOutput("age", container = span)),
                        h4("Peso (kg):", textOutput("weight", container = span)),
                        h4("Altura (cm):", textOutput("height", container = span))
                        
                      )
                    )
           ),
           tabPanel("Medição de glucose",
                    sidebarLayout(
                      sidebarPanel(
                        helpText("Preencha os campos abaixo para anotar a sua medição de glucose. Depois deve clicar em 'Submeter' para guardar a medição."),
                        #dateInput(inputId = "date", label = "Insira a data:",  value = Sys.Date(), format = "dd-mm-yyyy", language = "pt",  autoclose = T),
                        numericInput(inputId = "glicose", label = "Concentração de glicose", min = 50,  max = 400,  value = 0),
                        timeInput(inputId = "time", label =  "Insira a hora", value = Sys.time(), seconds = FALSE),
                        selectInput(inputId = "measurement", label = "Tipo de medição", choices = list("Em jejum" = 0, "Período pós-prandial" = 1), selected = NULL, multiple = F),
                        actionButton(inputId = "update", label = "Submeter")
                      ),
                      mainPanel(
                        dataTableOutput("glucosedf"),
                        #tableOutput("glucosetable"),
                        #plotOutput("glucoseplot")
                      )
                    )
           ),
           tabPanel("Informações Gerais",
                    numericInput(inputId = "utente", label = "Número de Utente", min = 0,  max = 999999999,  value = 0)
           ),
          )

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {

#Página 1
  
  name <- eventReactive(input$go, {input$name})
  email <- eventReactive(input$go, {input$email})
  address <- eventReactive(input$go, {input$address})
  phone <- eventReactive(input$go, {input$phone})
  utente <- eventReactive(input$go, {input$utente})
  age <- eventReactive(input$go, {input$age})
  weight <- eventReactive(input$go, {input$weight})
  height <- eventReactive(input$go, {input$height})
  
  output$name <- renderText({name()})
  output$email <- renderText({email()})
  output$address <- renderText({address()})
  output$phone <- renderText({phone()})
  output$utente <- renderText({utente()})
  output$age <- renderText({age()})
  output$weight <- renderText({weight()})
  output$height <- renderText({height()})
  
#Página 2
  
  values <- reactiveValues()
  if(file.exists('responses/values.csv')) values$df <- read.csv('responses/values.csv')
    else values$df <- data.frame("Glicose" = NULL, "Time" = NULL, "Measurement" = NULL)
  newEntry <- observe({
    if(input$update > 0) {
      newLine <- isolate(data.frame("Glicose" = input$glicose, "Time" = input$time, "Measurement" = input$measurement))
      isolate(values$df <- rbind(values$df, newLine))
      write.csv(values$df, "responses/values.csv", row.names = FALSE)
    }
  })
  #output$glucosetable <- renderDataTable({values$df})
  output$glucosedf <- renderDataTable({values$df}, options = list(columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center')), pageLength = 5, lengthMenu = c(5, 10)))

  #glucoseplot <- eventReactive(input$update, {values$df})
  #output$glucoseplot <- renderPlot({glucoseplot()})
  
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: can you provide a functional example of your shiny app? With UI function and server fuction and used packages. otherwise no one will be able to reproduce the error.

Comment: You could try to explicitly set the mode of your time column when creating dataframe `newLine` in your server code, using the appropriate `as.someMode(input$time)` function (e. g. `as.Date`). Package **lubridate** might come in handy.

Comment: @user12256545 I edited the post and added the full code. The app is meant to be a diabetes helper, where the pacient tracks its measures by adding contact info and biomeasurements (first tab) and records glycemic values by inputing the glicose concentration and date and time it was measured

Comment: @I_O that did not work. Only thing it did was remove the hour and minute info that was being added. The problem remains. When i close the app and run it again to add another entry, it changes the format

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `strptime`.

I simplified the example to keep it reproducible, because the question was regarding the time column.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTime)

ui <- fluidPage(
  timeInput(inputId = "time",
            label =  "Insira a hora",
            value = Sys.time(),
            seconds = FALSE),
  dataTableOutput("glucosedf"),
  actionButton(inputId = "update", label = "Submeter")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  values <- reactiveValues(
    df=data.frame(
      "Glicose" = NULL,
      "Time" = NULL,
      "Measurement" = NULL)
  )
  observeEvent(input$update, {
    values$df = rbind(
      values$df,
      data.frame("Glicose"=0,
                 "Time"=strptime(input$time,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                 "Measurement"=0)
    )
  })
  output$glucosedf <- renderDataTable({
    values$df
    })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: well, that did not work. Your code is way simpler while mine has a whole bunch of conditions, reactive Values and such. Maybe its cuz of that? I also read strptime is a python package and is not avaliable for my version of R, the latest version

Comment: strptime is a baseR function

Comment: Still not working. It saves on the desired format the first time, the it never does. Maybe it has to do with the file? I notice the .csv column names are between "". When i close the app and open the csv, the "" for the first column name is gone